# SSIS - How to read configuration values in script task code

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS package which contains several dataflow and script tasks. Each script tasks contains input parameters for webservice calls which I need to make it configurable. I would also like to move the connection string to the configuration file so that I can have different connection strings for each enviorment. I have managed to create configuration using Package Configuration in SSIS. How do I read these configuration values in my script tasks. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the configuration values to package variables, and access the variables in your script.

Comment: Thanks Tab! I'd mark this as the answer if I could!